# Print the longest common sequence

Tags: algorithm, python, data-structures

I am trying to implement solution of the classical problem, but I am confused as I get some cases where I don't find good results.

Output: "The Longest common sequence", "Length"

```
def longestCommonSeq(x,y):
    LCS = [[0 for z in range(len(y)+1)] for z in  range(len(x)+1)] 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        LCS[i][0]=0

    for j in range(len(y)):
        LCS[0][j]=0

    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[i]== y[j]:
                LCS[i][j]= 1+LCS[i-1][j-1]
            else: 
                LCS[i][j]= max(LCS[i-1][j],LCS[i][j-1])


    i, j= len(x),len(y)
    print LCS

    res = "" 
    while i>0 and j>0:

        if x[i-1]== y[j-1]:
            res= x[i-1] + res
            i-=1
            j-=1 
        else:
            if LCS[i-1][j]>LCS[i][j-1]:
                i-=1
            else: 
                j-=1

    return res, LCS[len(x)-1][len(y)-1]
```

For the first case:

```
x= "AGGTAB"
y= "GXTXAYB"
print longestCommonSeq(x,y)
```

**Result:**  `('GTAB', 4)`
This is right!

but for case like:

```
a= "APBCADCQER" 
b= "RASBTAUCVE"
print longestCommonSeq(a,b)

 ('', 5)
```

What did I miss ?, Can anyone give a hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building the table wrong; you should leave the row at `i = 0` and the column at `j = 0`  at 0 entirely, and put matches into the higher rows. This means you need to add 1 to the `i` and `j` coordinates in the first loop, as Python starts indices at 0.

As a result, you end up with a table with the 0s at the end; using notation similar to the [explanation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Worked_example) you essentially build this:

```
┌─┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬───────┬─┐
│ │A    │G        │G        │T    │A     │B      │ │
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│G│< ^ 0│\ G      │\ G      │< G  │< G   │< G    │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│X│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │< ^ G│< ^ G │< ^ G  │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│T│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │\ GT │< GT  │< GT   │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│X│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │^ GT │< ^ GT│< ^ GT │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│A│\ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │\ GTA │< GTA  │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│I│^ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │^ GTA │< ^ GTA│0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│B│^ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │^ GTA │\ GTAB │0│
├─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┼─┤
│ │0    │0        │0        │0    │0     │0      │0│
└─┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴───────┴─┘

< and ^: maximum picked
\: add matching character to cell to the top left.
```

This is leaving your last column and row set to 0 rather than the first. It is your luck that Python interprets `-1` as the last element, because at `i = 0` or `j = 0` that is exactly what you end up doing. What you want instead is:

```
┌─┬─┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ │ │A    │G        │G        │T    │A     │B      │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│ │0│0    │0        │0        │0    │0     │0      │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│G│0│< ^ 0│\ G      │\ G      │< G  │< G   │< G    │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│X│0│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │< ^ G│< ^ G │< ^ G  │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│T│0│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │\ GT │< GT  │< GT   │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│X│0│< ^ 0│^ G      │< ^ G    │^ GT │< ^ GT│< ^ GT │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│A│0│\ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │\ GTA │< GTA  │
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│I│0│^ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │^ GTA │< ^ GTA│
├─┼─┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼───────┤
│B│0│^ A  │< ^ A | G│< ^ A | G│^ GT │^ GTA │\ GTAB │
└─┴─┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Next, you don't need to consult `x` and `y` in the second loop, you consult *just* your `LCS` table. Because you ended up with `0`, always, in the last row and column, your version of the algorithm falls flat when the last character of `x` and `y` do not match and you just end up decrementing `i` and `j` almost randomly as you fail to hit the LCS path set out in the table.

Note that your first two `for` loops are entirely redundant and can be removed; your whole `LCS` table contains only `0` values, why set them to `0` some more? The pseudocode in Wikipedia uses a loop from 1 to the length (inclusive), but since Python starts at 0 and you add 1 to the length to keep the length inclusive, you don't need to do this here.

Your corrected function then looks like:

```
def longestCommonSeq(x,y):
    LCS = [[0 for z in range(len(y) + 1)] for z in range(len(x) + 1)] 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[i] ==  y[j]:
                LCS[i + 1][j + 1] = 1 + LCS[i][j]
            else: 
                LCS[i + 1][j + 1] = max(LCS[i][j + 1], LCS[i + 1][j])

    res = ''
    i, j = len(x), len(y)

    while i and j:
        if LCS[i][j] == LCS[i-1][j]:
            i -= 1
        elif LCS[i][j] == LCS[i][j-1]: 
            j -= 1
        else:
            res = x[i-1] + res
            i -= 1
            j -= 1

    return res, LCS[-1][-1]
```

Because the `LCS` table is now correctly built we can use `LCS[-1][-1]` as the maximum length value too.

This produces the expected results:

```
>>> x = "AGGTAB"
>>> y = "GXTXAYB"
>>> print longestCommonSeq(x, y)
('GTAB', 4)
>>> a = "APBCADCQER" 
>>> b = "RASBTAUCVE"
>>> print longestCommonSeq(a, b)
('ABACE', 5)
```

The alternative would be to fix the off-by-one in your second phase and look at the LCS table cells that actually correspond to your input words; e.g. subtracting 1 from `i` and `j`:

```
def longestCommonSeq(x,y):
    LCS = [[0 for z in range(len(y)+1)] for z in  range(len(x)+1)] 

    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[i] ==  y[j]:
                LCS[i][j] = 1 + LCS[i - 1][j - 1]
            else: 
                LCS[i][j] = max(LCS[i - 1][j], LCS[i][j - 1])

    i, j = len(x) - 1, len(y) - 1
    print LCS

    res = "" 
    while i >= 0 and j >= 0:
        if x[i] == y[j]:
            res= x[i] + res
            i -= 1
            j -= 1 
        else:
            if LCS[i - 1][j] > LCS[i][j - 1]:
                i -= 1
            else: 
                j -= 1

    return res, LCS[len(x) - 1][len(y) - 1]
```

Now `i` and `j` range from `len(x) - 1` to `0` and `len(y) - 1` to `0` respectively, and you are referencing the correct cells again.