# Longest Common Sequence -Index Error

Tags: python, matrix, lcs

I am trying to find the LCS between two sequences: TACGCTGGTACTGGCAT and AGCTGGTCAGAA. I want my answer to output as a matrix so that I can backtrack which sequence is common (GCTGGT). When I use my code below, I am getting the following error. IndexError: list index out of range. How can I avoid this error in my code below?

```
def LCS(x, y):
    m = len(x)
    n = len(y)
    C = []  
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if x[i] == y[j]:
                C[i][j] == C[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                C[i][j] == 0
    return C


x = "TACGCTGGTACTGGCAT"
y = "AGCTGGTCAGAA"
m = len(x)
n = len(y)
C = LCS(x, y)

print C
```

Comment: Related: [Print the longest common sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26077679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append to your list, because the index `[i][j]` does not exist yet.

```
def LCS(x, y):
    m = len(x)
    n = len(y)
    C = []  
    for i in range(m):
    C.append([])          # append a blank list at index [i]
        for j in range(n):
            if x[i] == y[j]:
                C[i].append(C[i-1][j-1] + 1)   # append current element to [i]
            else:
                C[i].append(0)
    return C
```

Testing

```
x = "TACGCTGGTACTGGCAT"
y = "AGCTGGTCAGAA"
LCS(x,y)
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!